# How to use Excel relationships between tables in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, relationship, excel-2013

I have imported my Excel database into SQL Server 2012 through the SQL Server Import and Export wizard. The tables and data are imported successfully but the relationships b/w tables are not. Is there any way to do it or it can't be done because I know it is possible the other way around

Comment: Excel is not a *database* ....

Comment: Yeah I know. But you can create relationships among the tables in excel.

Comment: @marc_s, can it be done?